# C# Display List<class> values in ListBox

Tags: c#, winforms, list, listbox

I am adding the "Procs" class as a List item:

```
public static List<Procs> allprocs = new List<Procs>();
```

So when a user fills out a form and clicks "Add Proceedure":

```
private void btAddProcedure_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ClaimVars.allprocs.Add(new Procs
    {

        TreatmentBusinessID = Convert.ToInt32(proLocID.Text),
        DiagCodeID = ClaimVars.DiagID,
        CPTCodeID = ClaimVars.CPTID,
        Charges = Convert.ToDouble(txtCharges.Text),
        AmountPaid = Convert.ToDouble(txtPaid.Text),
        DateServicedFrom = Convert.ToDateTime(dateTimePicker1.Text),
        DateServicedToo = Convert.ToDateTime(dateTimePicker2.Text),
        Notes = notesDiagServ.Text
    });

    // Change the DataSource.
    listBox1.DataSource = null;
    listBox1.DataSource = ClaimVars.allprocs;
    }
}
```

They will see a new list item.

How do I display the values of this class rather than adding the name of the object?

After adding a proceedures, this is how my listbox looks:

```
Project_LB223.ClaimForms.Procs
Project_LB223.ClaimForms.Procs
Project_LB223.ClaimForms.Procs
Project_LB223.ClaimForms.Procs
```

This is how I would like it to look:

```
1     32     44     33.44     22.17     12/17/09 11:21:52     12/22/09 10:31:64     patient was feeling sick.
2     42     72     12.45     10.67     12/18/09 22:51:22     12/23/09 11:21:25     patient was showing signs of fatigue and shortness of breath.
1     68     57     83.64     55.47     12/19/09 23:25:45     12/24/09 15:38:42     the patient is feeling better.
5     12     22     37.44     23.45     12/22/09 16:81:11     12/25/09 19:35:22     the patient does not have any more symptoms.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can, for example, add `ToString()` method override, like this:

```
public class Procs
{
    public override string ToString()
    {
       string spaceinbetween = new string(' ', 5);
       return TreatmentBusinessID + spaceinbetween + DiagCodeID + spaceinbetween ...
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Your data is displayed with a call to `ToString()`. You can override this method in your class to display the data however you like.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve a colum layout by using either

- override ToString() on the Procs class
- use the Format event of the listbox.

In both case you'll need to set a fixed-width font, so using a DataGrid or ListView might be better.

Answer (score 0):

A `ListBox` can't display multiple columns, use a [`DataGridView`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.aspx) instead.

Comment: I understand, datagrid is not an option. Even building a string with tabs inbetween values is acceptable.

Comment: Why is it not an option? Doing this with a ListBox will be ugly and very uncomfortable for the user...

Comment: The project was originally using GridView's im actually being paid to take them out haha.